# Get the names of tables created on a specific date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to know the names of the tables that were created on a specific date.

I am using SQL Server 2012.

Is there any query I can use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to query `sys.tables`:

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.tables
WHERE CONVERT(date, create_date) = 'YYYYMMDD'
```

`Create_date` is a `datetime` so you probably want to convert it.

Comment: I'd also suggest `YYYYMMDD` as a habit to pick up, though your query is fine :)

Comment: @scsimon I'm embarrassed I didn't write it that way to begin with

Comment: SELECT name
FROM sys.tables
WHERE CONVERT(date, create_date) = '20000101' -- YYYYMMDD format, which is ISO 8601 standard